# CoreData warning: Unrecognized optimized model archive format

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data

When running my iOS program on an iPad, the console gives the following error when opening the CoreData data store:

```
CoreData warning: Unrecognized optimized model archive format
Failed to load optimized model: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x150160 {Root cause=Unknown archive format}
```

Anyone got any ideas what this means? and how to fix?

Thanks.
Glen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always hard to say whether or not this was the fix, because it seems that what works for some people in Xcode doesn't work for others, but the way I finally got rid of this error was by cleaning the project and rebuilding.

Prior to that, I tried to delete the app and run the project again (without cleaning), but that still generated the error, so I think it just has to do with a cached model in the build folder that's messing up its ability to "load the optimized model".

Hope this helps!